# Referring people with SR-questions to test-bodies in the Schwarzschild solution?

Tags: discussion, answers, best-practices

I guess mostly because of how relativity is taught in schools, with a strong focus on exercises in special relativity where gravity is totally ignored and then maybe a little bit of info on general relativity, there are in my opinion a lot of questions on this site that is a bit strange in the fact that they ignore gravity.

I kind of wonder if it had been more pedagogic to start off with the effects in a spherical symmetric gravitational field and then treat the case of no gravity as some kind of special case.

There are a lot of questions on time dilation from an SR perspective on this site. Usually, in a real life scenario, where you are close to the Earth and can ignore other celestial bodys or when you are in the solar system and can ignore other bodies then the sun, you can treat "the twins" or whoever is experiencing time dilation as two test-bodies in the Schwarzschild solution. I wonder if it would be beneficial to the understanding of the laymen, to take this approach more often in different answers.

In [this answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/480739/226214) on time experienced by the Voyager space craft I did just that but there are many questions of the same kind that has a strange answer in SR but a less contradictable solution in GR. For instance there are questions on [muon decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149213/confusion-about-length-contraction-ex-in-muon-decay?).

**Question**: Should there be some kind of effort to push answers to questions where the person who asks seems to have a clear SR perspective on time dilation (or maybe sometimes length contraction) where gravity is ignored into a GR explanation at least to the level of most simple spherically symmetric case?

Comment: This question is completely unclear to me. What is you're proposing we do?

Comment: What do you mean by “strong focus on the sometimes "unfinished" theory of special relativity”?

Comment: If you break your 4 line long sentences into smaller ones, or at least you use much more "`,`", it would help a lot.

Comment: I changed a few sentences to address your concerns yesterday.